# How to make JavaScript form error disappear after immediately after new input is provided?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var nameInput = formHandle.f_Name;
var idInput = formHandle.f_Id;   

// NAME VALIDATION
        if(nameInput.value === ""){ 
                nameMsg = document.getElementById("nameErr");
                nameMsg.style.background = "red"; 
                nameMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter your name."; 
                nameMsg.style.color = "white";
                nameInput.focus();
                return false;
        }
    
        
// ID VALIDATION
        if(idInput.value === ""){
            idMsg = document.getElementById("idErr");
            idMsg.style.background = "red"; 
            idMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter the correct ID."; 
            idMsg.style.color = "white";
            idInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
```

First my name field is validated. If it is empty, a red alert appears. However once I edit the empty name field, add a name and hit submit again, the empty ID field is detected. When this happens I want only the ID field to be red and the name field should not continue to display an error as the conditions have been met. How do I do that?

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2AF3.png)

Comment: You have to listen to the "input" event of each input field, and set idMsg and nameMsg innerHTML to an empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i think you should add an else statement to the input field... like this...


var nameInput = formHandle.f_Name;
var idInput = formHandle.f_Id;   

// NAME VALIDATION
        if(nameInput.value === ""){ 
                nameMsg = document.getElementById("nameErr");
                nameMsg.style.background = "red"; 
                nameMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter your name."; 
                nameMsg.style.color = "white";
                nameInput.focus();
                return false;
        } else { 
           nameMsg = document.getElementById("nameErr");
                nameMsg.style.display= "none";
}
    
        
// ID VALIDATION
        if(idInput.value === ""){
            idMsg = document.getElementById("idErr");
            idMsg.style.background = "red"; 
            idMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter the correct ID."; 
            idMsg.style.color = "white";
            idInput.focus();
            return false;
        }else { 
            idMsg = document.getElementById("idErr");
            idMsg.style.display= "none"; 
        
}
```

Comment: This would provide the desired effect if you call the validation function every time the value of the input changes. You can do that with:
addEventListener('input', function () { });

Comment: Sure. But is there any other way around it? Perhaps using onChange event?

Comment: If you are using JQuery you can use onChange, but the workaround with pure JS would be as I wrote in the first comment, adding an event listener to the input element, listening to 'input'

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use CSS classes.

Define a CSS class like:

```
.error-input {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

then you can use Javascript to toggle this class:

```
if(nameInput.value === ""){ 
  nameMsg = document.getElementById("nameErr");
  nameInput.classList.add("error-input");
  nameMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter your name."; 
  nameInput.focus();
  return false;
} else {
  nameInput.classList.remove("error-input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is hide all errors before validation:

```
var nameInput = formHandle.f_Name;
var idInput = formHandle.f_Id;   

nameMsg = document.getElementById("nameErr");
idMsg = document.getElementById("idErr");

nameMsg.style.display = "none";
idMsg.style.display = "none";

// NAME VALIDATION
    if(nameInput.value === ""){ 
            nameMsg.style.background = "red"; 
            nameMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter your name."; 
            nameMsg.style.color = "white";
            nameMsg.style.display = "inline-block";
            nameInput.focus();
            return false;
    }

    
// ID VALIDATION
    if(idInput.value === ""){
        idMsg.style.background = "red"; 
        idMsg.innerHTML = "Please enter the correct ID."; 
        idMsg.style.color = "white";
        idMsg.style.display = "inline-block";
        idInput.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This did not provide me with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way now is to use HTML5 `input` elements to manage the validation for you. In this example if neither of the values in the inputs are correct the form simply won't validate, and you'll get some warnings why. And you've also got a nice way of representing that through the CSS pseudo-class `:invalid`.

```js
// Caching the form element and adding a listener to it
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {

  // When the form is valid prevent it from
  // submitting - in this instance! - and
  // log all the input values
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    console.log(input.value);
  });
}
```

```css
input { border: 2px solid black; display: block; }
input:invalid { border: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<form>
  Number<input type="number" placeholder="A number" />
  Name<input type="text" placeholder="Letters" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" />
  Email<input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```